# ORACLE SQL Errors 127 and 396

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

For a long time Oracle, as soon as I start the program, gives me these two errors that I have not been able to solve or understand.

***1st mistake***

```
LEVEL: SEVERE

Sequence: 396

Elapsed: 60969

Source: oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$1

Message: NORTHWIND expired 0.003s ago (see "Caused by:" stack trace below); reported from ExpiredTextBuffer on thread AWT-EventQueue-0 activate AWT event:
java.awt.event.FocusEvent[FOCUS_LOST,permanent,opposite=null,cause=CLEAR_GLOBAL_FOCUS_OWNER] on Editor2_MAIN at oracle.ide.model.ExpiredTextBuffer.newExpiredTextBufferException(ExpiredTextBuffer.java:55)
```

***2nd Error***

```
LEVEL: SEVERE

sequence: 127

Elapsed: 0

Source: oracle.ide.extension.HashStructureHook

Message: Unexpected runtime exception while delivering HashStructureHookEvent
```

**I have tried to reinstall everything and it is not due to lack of resources either since the pc is quite powerful ryzen 9 and 32gb of ram**

Comment: This is probably off-topic and something to ask about in the SQL Developer forum or raise a service request about; but you should at least include the SQL Developer version number, and maybe the JDK version.